# How to use or function in a while loop python?

Tags: python, while-loop

Some of my code...

```
reenter = "T"
while reenter != "f" and reenter != "F":
    n1 = int(input("Please enter the first number in your equation : "))
    o = str(input("Please enter the operation (/,*,-,+)           : "))
    n2 = int(input("Please enter the second number in your equation: "))
    reenter = input(n1  + o + n2 is your Formula is this correct? T/F?")
```

I need to cater for both capitalised and uncapitalised f. Ths issue is it won't exit the loop, help??

Thank in advance - Zyrn

Comment: Please mention Python version you are using.

Comment: Asides from the fact that the T/F logic in the last input is inverted, the loop exists just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `input()` for user input, rather `raw_input()`.
The difference is that `input()` tries to evaluate the user input, which is not what you want.
Also some other issues with string formatting, etc., check below.

```
reenter = "T"
while reenter != "f" and reenter != "F":
    n1 = int(raw_input("Please enter the first number in your equation : "))
    o = raw_input("Please enter the operation (/,*,-,+) : ")
    n2 = int(input("Please enter the second number in your equation: "))
    reenter = raw_input("{}{}{} is your Formula is this correct? T/F?".format(n1, o, n2))
```

P.S. Not sure what you are trying to do, but it seems that you may want to invert the "T"/"F" logic there? :)